# python regular expression to extract and replace query parameters - cx_oracle requirement

Tags: python, sql, regex, cx-oracle

The python module cx_Oracle requires that queries be parameterized if strings are being passed in the **where** statement. I am reading queries off a file, and these queries look exactly how you would execute them from an IDE like sql developer.

**Example Query**

```
select name, count(1) from employees where status = 'Active' and role= 'Manager' group by name order by 1;
```

I want write some function that will take this query as an input and then spit out the parameters as a tuple:

```
query = 'select name, count(1) from employees where status = :1 and role= :2 group by name order by 1;'
parms = ('Active','Manager')
```

That way i can pass the two in a simple function to execute the query:

```
cursor_object.execute(query,parms)
```

Unfortunately, I am god awful at regular expressions, and I've been trying my hand at this for hours to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import re

sql = """select name, count(1) from employees where status = 'Active' and role= 'Manager' group by name order by 1;"""

rx = re.compile(r"""\w+\s*=\s*'([^']+)'""")
params = rx.findall(sql)
print(params)
# ['Active', 'Manager']
```

With the main part being

```
\w+\s*=\s*'([^']+)'
```

Broken down, this says:

```
\w+\s*    # 1+ word characters, 0+ whitespace characters
=\s*      # =, 0+ whitespace characters
'([^']+)' # '(...)' -> group 1
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/eHPT39/1).

---

To have both the query and the params, you could write a small function:

```
import re

sql = """select name, count(1) from employees where status = 'Active' and role= 'Manager' group by name order by 1;"""

rx = re.compile(r"""(\w+\s*=\s*)'([^']+)'""")

def replacer(match):
    replacer.params.append(match.group(2))
    return '{}:{}'.format(match.group(1), len(replacer.params))

replacer.params = list()
query = rx.sub(replacer, sql)
params = replacer.params

print(query)
print(params)
# select name, count(1) from employees where status = :1 and role= :2 group by name order by 1;
# ['Active', 'Manager']
```

As noted in the comments, you need to reset the params list for each query you want to analyze.

Comment: Thank you for taking the extra time to explain the expression. Your break down and linking the demo have definitely helped me understand how an expression is built.

Comment: Quick follow up question: how can the "replacer" function reference itself before being fully defined? I've heard of self-referential functions, but never seen one in action.

Comment: @sikrut: In `Python`, functions are objects just like everything else, so you can add a property like `params`, which itself can be a string, a list or even another function.

Comment: @Jan : if you call the `replacer` function multiple times, you accumulate the parameters of all calls. You need to reset the list before each call: `replacer.params = []`…

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE: That's definitely something to be aware of, yes. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty solution is the write a RegEx which match the quoted string. You can start like this:

```
import re
import textwrap

query = textwrap.dedent("""\
select name, count(1)
from employees
where status = 'Active' and role= 'Manager'
group by name order by 1;""")

sub_var = re.compile(r"'[^']+'").sub

print(sub_var("VAR", query))
# select name, count(1)
# from employees
# where status = VAR and role= VAR
# group by name order by 1;
```

But, here you need to replace by an value which increments itself for each match.

To do that, you need a function. Remember that `re.sub` can take a callable as a replacement sting. The callable must take a MatchObject as a parameter and return the replacement.

Here, I prefer used a callable class:

```
class CountVar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    def __call__(self, mo):
        self.count += 1
        return ":{0}".format(self.count)


print(sub_var(CountVar(), query))
# select name, count(1)
# from employees
# where status = :1 and role= :2
# group by name order by 1;
```

Here it is!

Comment: Thank you for this solution. Interesting seeing multiple expression version. Why use a class instead of a function of functions? I probably mean that more fundamentally, since I've really only ever used functions in my pet projects. _self taught without much experience_

Answer (score 0):

The only issue with Jan's answer is that it does not produce the string with ":1", ":2", etc. that you want.

Something like the following should work:

```
import re
i=1
pattern = r"(?<==\s*)'\w+'"
params = []
while True:
    match = re.find( pattern, cmd )
    if match is None: break
    params.append(match.group())
    cmd = re.sub( pattern, ":" + str(i), 1 )
    i += 1
```

In the pattern, the `(?<=)` is called a positive lookbehind and makes sure that the argument (in this case `=\s*`, an equals followed by any number of spaces) comes before the part that is matched, but it is not included as part of the match (so it will not be included in `params` or get replaced in the substitution).

Comment: Nice to see this done in a loop, as well as an additional expression. Didn't realize they were so flexible, but maybe that's what also makes them a bit difficult to pick up.